# getting "Cannot GET /public/signup.html" error in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Very new to express and file system and don't have much idea about directories so getting this error.

```
var express= require('express');
var path= require('path');
var mysql= require('mysql');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');

var app= express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.set( {
    'Access-control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});
return res.redirect('/public/signup.html');
 }).listen(2121);

console.log('server Running on : 2121');
app.use('/public',express.static(__dirname +"/public"));
```

Getting error "Cannot GET /public/signup.html"
My directories is:

```
-Express
--Server.js
--public
---signup.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `listen` on `app` before you call `use` on your middleware and there are a few mistakes in your code. I think this should work:

```
app
  .use('/public',express.static(`${__dirname}/public`))
  .get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.header({
      'Access-control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
    res.redirect(`${req.baseUrl}/public/signup.html`);
  })
  .listen(2121);
```

Comment: But what if I want to add the directory to access multiple files later in the program.

Comment: Sorry, I realised I had misunderstood what your code was doing and edited my answer. You need to call `use` before you call `listen`. I had this same issue myself a few days ago. With the edited code you should have access to the public directory no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is a little jumbled up. Separate out your port listener - this should always come last. Add your routes and middleware before that as individual calls to `app`, and also register your get request to redirect back to your server to the signup html.

This should work:

```js
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");

var port = 2121;
var app = express();

// Register Middlewares/Headers
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
});

// Register Static
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

// Register redirect
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(req.baseUrl + '/public/signup.html');
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server Running on : ", port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide

```
app.use('/public',express.static(__dirname +"/public"));
```

Before you using `app.get`

Full example:

```
var express= require('express');
var path= require('path');
var mysql= require('mysql');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');

var app= express();
app.use('/public',express.static(__dirname +"/public"));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.set( {
       'Access-control-Allow-Origin': '*'
   });
   return res.redirect('/public/signup.html');
 }).listen(2121);

console.log('server Running on : 2121');
```